# Calendar: adding a day time the button is clicked [Java]

Tags: java, calendar

```
class calendarNDListener implements  ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
            date = new Date();

            calendar.setTime(date);
            calendar.add(calendar.DATE, 1);
            date = calendar.getTime();

            dag.setText(format.format(date));
        }
```

When I click the button that has the 'calendarNDListener' ActionListener to it, it adds one day to the 'dag' label. But this does it only once. If I want to go another day ahead, it doesn't do anything. 
What I want is, when you click the button, it adds a day to the label date. But if I click it again, it adds a day to the previous date (the one that already has a day added to it). It's now 2 days ahead of the current day.

What I want: 
Today is 28/03. When I click the button, it goes to 29/03. When I click it again, it goes to 30/03 and so on.

What it does now:
Today is 28/03. When I click the button, it goes to 29/03. When I click it again, it stays at 29/03.

I hope this was clear enough, it might sound confusing.
Bear in mind that I'm still a beginner in Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

the question was asked before!
do your research instead of just posting a question!
this is your answer:

```
public class DateUtil
{
    public static Date addDays(Date date, int days)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days); //minus number would decrement the days
        return cal.getTime();
    }
}
```

To add one day, per click, call it like this:

```
String sourceDate = "2012-02-29";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date myDate = format.parse(sourceDate);
myDate = DateUtil.addDays(myDate, 1);
```

Comment: I am getting an error on the "Date myDate = format.parse(sourceDate);" code: Unhandled exception type ParseException. Any solution?

Comment: surround statement with a `try/catch` block.. `Netbeans` usually suggests that automatically..

Comment: Alright, that fixed it. After all that, do I edit the label like this: "dag.setText(format.format(myDate));" ?